# Getting distinct values by two fields

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<T>` object:

```
List<MyCampaignClass> campaignsToProcess = new List<MyCampaignClass>();
```

I do some filtering on upstream data via `LINQ`.

```
var results= from h in campaignHistory
             join a in campaignAvailability
             on new { h.campaignId, h.reportDate } equals new { a.campaignId, a.reportDate }
             where h.operationDate >= a.startDate
             select h;
```

Then I add it to my running `List<T>` object.  I want distinct by two values in the declared class: `MyCampaignClass.campaignId` and `MyCampaignClass.reportDate`.

```
results.Select(m =>
    new MyCampaignClass()
    {
        campaignId = m.campaignId,
        reportDate = m.reportDate
    })
    .Distinct() //doesn't work
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => campaignsToProcess.Add(p));
```

I can't wrap my head around why `.Distinct()` isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by `isn't working.`

Comment: What's being added to my running list in the line `.ForEach(p => campaignsToProcess.Add(p))`.  I'm gettingi duplicates.

Comment: `Distinct` relies on the objects in your collection overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` if they don't then it will use reference equality and likely everything is "distinct".  There is an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that you can use though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way, you can use an *anonymous type* first then make another projection to convert them  `MyCampaignClass`

```
historyResults
.Select(m => new { m.campaignId, m.reportDate })
.Distinct()
.Select(m =>
new MyCampaignClass()
{
    campaignId = m.campaignId,
    reportDate = m.reportDate
});
```

This will work because anonymous types are compared by property values rather than their references.

Another way is to override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` method properly in your `MyCampaignClass` or implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your class and pass it to `Distinct` method.

Comment: Neat trick to select an anonymous type! Another solution is to implement `DistinctBy` like the one in MoreLinq http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs